# Error. The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator. When calling wsdl service

Tags: iis, windows-firewall

I am trying to connect to a wsdl service trought my network to the internet, and getting The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator. Your support ID is: 13403249542993459449. This is inside .NET Application. That was worked fine until now.

When testing the service in SOAPUI is OK, but not in the calling service on IIS.

Code used to call service:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlconfig);
                byte[] bytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(s);
                httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
                httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (RemoteCertificateValidationCallback)((sender1, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
                using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                string end = new StreamReader(httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The error message is clear. You should contact the server administrators for assistance, as they know the web application and who to escalate.

Comment: There are many reasons for this problem, cache is one of them, you can try clear cache and cookies, then try again.

Comment: Try encoding the request body as Base64 text (but you will have to decoded it on the server). It's possible that the target server is rejecting your request because the request body contains suspicious HTML or something that is possibly malicious.